# How early before departure can I reserve train tickets in Belgium?

Tags: trains, tickets, bookings, belgium

I'm trying to book a train journey in Belgium for the end of July. We are currently in mid-June and the Belgian Rail website does not allow me to reserve tickets such a long time (~1 month) in advance.

So here is the question: how early can I reserve train tickets in Belgium?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[From this document](http://www.belgianrail.be/en/travel-tickets/tickets/~/media/F96A665043C842BEB420E4020B50C2B8.pdf), from the Belgian Rail official site, page 1, middle of the page:

> Vous pouvez acheter votre billet maximum 31 jours à l’avance.

That is, you can buy your ticket at maximum 31 days before departure. Note that this apply to standard, occasional ticket.

Comment: Have you tried to use the English language version of the site? (Or the German or Dutch ones?)

Comment: @Willeke apart that in the list of languages I can understand by intuition German and Dutch are not included, not even by mistake...yes, I used the English site :-) Just, documents containing detailed explanations like these are available only in French and Dutch

Comment: I just tried the English version, I was given options to buy for about a month in advance but for all further dates the site 'could not sell' https://www.belgianrail.be/en/timetable-and-buy-tickets/Search/secure/buy-your-ticket-step-1.aspx?ticketid=0&fromstationid=4001&tostationid=1009&date=18-07-2017&itineraryid=1

Comment: As I happen to be very close to a Belgian train-station at this time, I just walked in and asked at the ticket-counter. The very helpful people there told me also it was 1 month in advance, but said that 1 month is reckoned not in days, but on basis of "the day of the month". E.g ticket for September 11 is available as of August 11. Not sure if they got it right. That would be messy for ordering tickets for end of March.

Comment: @Tonny that totally sounds like an answer.

Comment: @motoDrizzt: I'm not Belgian, but French ;) I find your translation spot on, and it indeed appears that you cannot reserve this kind of tickets more than 31 in advance.